# How to use Facelets' ui:repeat tag in JSP?

Tags: jsp, jsf-2, facelets

I am using JSF 2.0 on JSP 2.1. Is there any possibility to use Facelets' `<ui:repeat>` tag in JSP files?

I have imported the Facelets taglib in JSP as

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" prefix="ui"%>
```

But it is not identifying the taglib `ui.taglib.xml` that comes with `jsf-impl.jar` and gives an error in render time as

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

But this `<ui:repeat>` tag works fine in my Facelets files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not possible. Facelets is a distinct view technology and technically the successor of JSP. You cannot mix them nor use Facelets tags in JSP files. For JSF2 it's *strongly* recommended to use Facelets instead of JSP as it's far superior over JSP.

For JSP, your best bet is using [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) [`<c:forEach>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) instead. It has similar syntax, only the `items` attribute is been used instead of `value`. Or if it needs to be a render-time tag like `<ui:repeat>` instead of a build-time tag, then consider looking at [Tomahawk's](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/index.html) [`<t:dataList>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_dataList.html).

Comment: Hi BalusC! Many thanks for your reply, yes it works fine with "<c:forEach>".